# "too many open files" from "npm install" when running in an AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, npm, aws-lambda, npm-install

We have just upgraded to node 18.15.0 and we’re having a problem where running “npm install” inside an AWS Lambda function leads to a “Too Many Open Files” error.  The same function has been working fine with 16.8.0.  So apparently the latest npm is nore wasteful with file handles?  Can anyone shed any light on this problem?

We are running this on an EFS volume.  The Lambda keeps a local tree of source files up to date with changes made to a Github repo, and the Lambda runs "npm install" as part of this process.  The consumers of these repos are ECS Fargate instances.  If I run the same operation on one of those instances, it will complete with no errors.  So it's pretty clear that the restrictiveness of the Lambda environment that is key here.  I suppose that running on an EFS volume could have something to do with this.

I can’t even think of a work-around.  If anyone else can, I’d love to hear your thoughts.  Like maybe some way of breaking the install into batches of dependent packages?

It isn't surprising, of course, that we're seeing this inside an AWS Lambda.  The Lambda environment tends to be more restrictive in any number of ways. Already thinking of the ugly work-around of having our lambda fire off an EC2 instance to run "npm install".

Answer (score 1):

NodeJS uses OS system calls to open each file.
And the *ix systems use `File Descriptors` to control the open files.

[AWS Lambda has a hard limit of 1024 file descriptors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html).

NPM and its package environment are famous for not being the most efficient in terms of number of files and packages.

Maybe that is the problem.
During your `npm install` it can reach the AWS Lambda File Descriptors limit.

Comment: Are there any potential workarounds, or does the limit essentially render AWS Lambda useless for "npm install" commands?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend setting the mpm cache to the Efs mount.

Comment: Please elaborate how to do that and explain why it helps to solve the problem, try for [answer].

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).